# How do you get an orthogonal vector in arbitrary dimensions?

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, numerical-methods, computational-geometry

The context is, I am trying to create a program to calculate the gradient of a discretized surface, i.e. a mesh. The trick however is, I need to do this on arbitrary dimensions.

I was given this formula:

[image]

That numerator is all fine and dandy in 3D, since to get the orthognal of that line you can just define the $\perp$ operator as $N\times (x_k - x_j)$, where $N$ is the normal to the triangle.

This however relies on the cross product, which does not exist in most dimensions. If instead of a mesh I have a hyper mesh, how can I get a vector that is both orthogonal to the hyper edge and contained in the hyper face?

To clarify, the diagram I have posted is one of the key steps needed to compute a discrete gradient on a 3D mesh (i.e a 2D manifold). In that setting the formula I posted is well defined through the operator I described earlier. It will give you a vector that is both contained in the triangle and orthogonal to the edge.

Consider now the same pattern one dimension above, i.e. a 3D manifold embedded in a 4D space. Each hyper face is a tetrahedron in 4D. The extension of the above formula would be; to find a vector that is embedded in the 3D subspace spanned by the vectors of the tetrahedron; and orthogonal to a vector that is orthogonal to all the vectors in that subspace (the hyper normal $N$).

One of the answers to this question describes a beautiful way to calculate $N$, however that's only half the problem, we need a vector that is orthogonal to $N$ and to one of the faces of the tetrahedron (in the example).

Comment: If all you need is a reliable method for finding a vector which is orthogonal to a given subspace, then the QR factorization is the way forward. Your question mentions further restrictions but you do not connect the key terms hyper edge and hyper face with your drawing. You edit your question and add this information.

Comment: @CarlChristian I edited the question, hopefully that makes it a bit clearer.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't see what you need more than just.one vector that is orthogonal to an arbitrary set of set of vectors?

Comment: Oh, your comment made me realize that yes, the problem is indeed just calculating N and then picking a new set of vectors containing N to get the final one.

Comment: No worries. Stripping away the packaging until one is left with the core problem is often  more than half the struggle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer contains a solution which has the following properties

1. It works even if the given vectors are linearly dependent.
2. It works in floating point arithmetic.
3. It requires only $O(n^3)$ arithmetic operations.

Let $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_k$ denote $k$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $k \leq n$ and $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$ denote the (tall) matrix whose $j$th column is $x_j$. Let $X = QR$ denote a QR factorization of $X$. Then $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is orthogonal, i.e. $Q^TQ=I_n$ is the $n$-by-$n$ identity matrix and $R \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$ is upper triangular. It follows that
$$ V = \text{span}\{x_1, x_2, \dotsc, x_k\} \subseteq \text{span}\{q_1, q_2, \dotsc, q_k\}$$
where $q_j$ is the $j$th column of $Q$. Moreover, if $k<n$, then $q_{k+1}, q_{k+2}, \dotsc q_n$ are all perpendicular to $V$ which is more than what is required here.

The QR factorization can be computed using the modified Gram-Schmidt method with or without column pivoting, using Givens rotations or using Householder reflectors. LAPACK implements Householder reflectors. The use of orthogonal transformations avoids many numerical issues which appear in real applications. The cost of doing a QR factorization of a general dense $n$ by $n$ matrix is $O(n^3)$ regardless of the method.

---

Avoid using determinants in practical computations if at all possible. The question of computing even a 2-by-2 determinant in a reliable manner is quite complex.

Answer (score 3):

If you have $n-1$ linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, you can find a vector orthogonal to them all in pretty much the same way.

Given $\vec{x}_1$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$: $\det\begin{bmatrix}\vec{e}_1&\vec{e}_2\\x_{11}&x_{12}\end{bmatrix}$

Given $\vec{x}_1,\vec{x}_2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$: $\det\begin{bmatrix}\vec{e}_1&\vec{e}_2&\vec{e}_3\\x_{11}&x_{12}&x_{13}\\x_{21}&x_{22}&x_{23}\end{bmatrix}$

Given $\vec{x}_1,\vec{x}_2,\vec{x}_3$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$: $\det\begin{bmatrix}\vec{e}_1&\vec{e}_2&\vec{e}_3&\vec{e}_4\\x_{11}&x_{12}&x_{13}&x_{14}\\x_{21}&x_{22}&x_{23}&x_{24}\\x_{31}&x_{32}&x_{33}&x_{34}\end{bmatrix}$

And so on. While computing the determinant, just treat the $\vec{e}_i$ as abstract symbols. But then you end up with an expression you intepret as a vector, and it is guaranteed orthogonal to all of the the $n-1$ vectors. It will be nonzero if the $n-1$ vectors are independent. I leave the proof to you and/or references.

Comment: This gives me the normal to the hyper face, how can I use it to find the orthogonal component to the line? Since the cross product is not necessarily defined.

i.e. I also need to find a vector $V$ that is contained in the hyper plane and orthogonal to one of the edges of the triangle.

Comment: This gives you the $N$ in the post, and you also have a line given by $\vec{x}_i$ and $\vec{x}_j$. You can break down $\overline{x_ix_j}$ into a component parallel to $N$ and a component orthogonal to $N$. This relies on the dot product. The parallel component will be $\frac{(\vec{x}_i-\vec{x}_j)\cdot N}{N\cdot N}N$, and the orthogonal component is the difference: $(\vec{x}_i-\vec{x}_j)-\frac{(\vec{x}_i-\vec{x}_j)\cdot N}{N\cdot N}N$.

Comment: Since the line is contained in the hyper surface, and $N$ is orthogonal to that surface, it follows that $N \cdot(x_i - x_j) = 0$. That won't give a vector that is orthogonal to both the line and the normal, contained in the hyper surface.

Comment: You used the phrase "orthogonal component". To me that means you have two vectors A and B, and are breaking down A as a sum A1+A2, where A1 is parallel to B and A2 is orthogonal to B. But I'm sensing that isn't what you meant.

Comment: You have $n$ determinants of size $n-1$. Normally, each determinant requires $O(n^3)$ operations. Can your scheme be completed using less than $O(n^4)$ operations?

Comment: @CarlChristian I didn't claim this was computationally efficient. It was a quick answer to OP's question. I still don't understand what OP's question in the first comment here is about. Doesn't your answer also produce a vector normal to the hyperface when $k=n-1$? (And when the $n-1$ vectors are edges with a common point?)

Comment: No, you didn't claim that it was computationally efficient. I am asking if the complexity can be reduced to $O(n^3)$.  Regardless, the determinants are vulnerable to subtractive cancellation to the point where OP's practical application can suffer badly. There is a cure for tiny matrices, but it doesn't generalize easily. The context of OP's question is not completely clear to me even after the edit. It has emerge that it is enough to construct a vector which is orthogonal to a set of vectors.